# Regex for getting integers and hyphen with spaces (special pattern recognition)

Tags: java, regex

Here is the data I want to capture (10 - 12) <===== This format

Sample Data:

```
sdfdsfsdffsd 16.50sd - 57676766.0sd
16.50sd - 57676766.0sd
16.50sd - 57676766.0sd
sdfsdffsdf 6sd - 5.989898989sd sdfsdsdf
sdfdsf 6.50sd - 76.50sd sdfsdfsd
sdfsf sd 12sd - 15sd sdfdsdffsdff
16.50sd - 57sd
16sd - 50sd
1.50sd - 5.0sd
1sd - 5766.34sd the sdfdsfdsf spesdfdsfed
1sd - 5766.34sd the ssdfsdf  sdfsdf
```

Here is what I have so far for a regex

```
[^\w\.\n]((\s?\-?\s?)(\d*(?=\.)))
```

Here is the result:
Link Here https://regex101.com/r/KNvHn8/1

So

1. Required format (16 - 55)
2. Sample Data blah blah 16.50 - 55.30 blah blah blah
   I need the Integers before the decimal points (16) ( - ) (55)

I can achieve this with 2 regex but preferable needs one.

Thanks

Comment: You dropped a word from your question #2. It would also be faster to provide a link to the current progress rather than a image link

Comment: How can i add a link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want the first digits before the dot and there has to be a hyphen in between, you can use 2 capture groups:

```
(\d+)(?:\.\d+)?[^\s\d-]*(\s-\s)[^\d-]*(\d+)
```

**Explanation**

- `(\d+)` Capture 1+ digits in group 2
- `(?:\.\d+)?` Optionally match `.` and 1+ digits
- `[^\s\d-]*` Optionally match any char except a whitespace char, digit or -
- `(\s-\s)` Capture `-` between whitespace chars in group 2
- `[^\d-]*` Optionally match any char except `-` or a digit
- `(\d+)` Capture 1+ digits in group 3

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SKyroG/1)

If you want the result on a line, you can use a replacement with the 3 groups:

```
^\D*(\d+)(?:\.\d+)?[^\s\d-]*(\s-\s)[^\d-]*(\d+).*
```

Example

```
String regex = "^\\D*(\\d+)(?:\\.\\d+)?[^\\s\\d-]*(\\s-\\s)[^\\d-]*(\\d+).*";
String string = "sdfdsfsdffsd 16.50sd - 57676766.0sd\n"
+ "16.50sd - 57676766.0sd\n"
+ "16.50sd - 57676766.0sd\n"
+ "sdfsdffsdf 6sd - 5.989898989sd sdfsdsdf\n"
+ "sdfdsf 6.50sd - 76.50sd sdfsdfsd\n"
+ "sdfsf sd 12sd - 15sd sdfdsdffsdff\n"
+ "16.50sd - 57sd\n"
+ "16sd - 50sd\n"
+ "1.50sd - 5.0sd\n"
+ "1sd - 5766.34sd the sdfdsfdsf spesdfdsfed\n"
+ "1sd - 5766.34sd the ssdfsdf  sdfsdf";
String subst = "$1$2$3";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

System.out.println( matcher.replaceAll("$1$2$3"));
```

Output

```
16 - 57676766
16 - 57676766
16 - 57676766
6 - 5
6 - 76
12 - 15
16 - 57
16 - 50
1 - 5
1 - 5766
1 - 5766
```

See a [Java demo](https://ideone.com/d1vupT)

Comment: for the first digit I just want the numbers before the dot, then the second group should be (space hyphen space) and the numbers up till the decimal place

Comment: @HClewlow Like this? https://regex101.com/r/SKyroG/1

Comment: 1 16.50sd - 57676766 is the result your regex gets but what i would like to achieve is (16 - 57676766)

Comment: @HClewlow You have the value 16 and 57676766 in group 1 and group 3. What do you want to achieve? Replace the whole line and leave only those values? Or print the values of the capture groups?

Comment: remove everything but "16 - 55565656" ie the numbers without decimal places and keep the (space hyphen space)

Comment: @HClewlow I have added an example how to use a replacement with the capture groups.

Comment: Works like a charm was "banging my head against a wall for ages"